# Read hdfs file in unix shell script

Tags: hbase

I have a text file in HDFS location, i want to read the file using unix shell script (bash profile).

Answer (score 0):

you can find many how-to for this specific use-case on web. It is one of the most besic operations.

```
#!/bin/bash
hdfs dfs -cat /your/path/in/hdfs > some_file_on_local_computer
```